# Printing values stored as dictionary in a list while loading from a file

Tags: python

I am loading a text file and trying to display its data. The data is in a form of list containing multiple dictionary values such as:

```
[{"name": "Oliver", "author": "Twist", "read": false}, {"name": "Harry", "author": "Potter", "read": true}, {"name": "Saitao", "author": "Apratim", "read": false}]
```

My read function is defined as follows:

```
def show_all_books():
    with open('data.txt','r') as f:
        books_list = f.read()
        print(books_list)
        if books_list == []:
            print('No books in the database!')
        else:
            for book in books_list:
                read = 'Yes' if book['read'] else 'No'
                print("The book {} authored by {} has been read?: {}".format(book['name'],book['author'],book['read']))
```

And the error I get is the following:

```
    read = 'Yes' if book['read'] else 'No'
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: your `books_list` is simply a string. To convert it to the list of dicts that you clearly want, you'll need to use the `json` module. (I'm assuming this file is valid JSON, it appears to be such at first glance but I haven't checked in detail.)

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on debugging your code. Hint: check the value and type of `books_list`. It isn't what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robin Zigmond suggested, you could convert the string into an object.

```
import json

def show_all_books():
    with open('data.txt','r') as f:
        books_list = f.read()
        books = json.loads(books_list)
        if books == []:
            print('No books in the database!')
        else:
            for book in books:
                if book['read']:
                    read = 'Yes'
                else:
                    read = 'No'
                print("The book {} authored by {} has been read?: {}".format(book['name'],book['author'], read))

show_all_books()
```

Then you get this:

```
The book Oliver authored by Twist has been read?: No
The book Harry authored by Potter has been read?: Yes
The book Saitao authored by Apratim has been read?: No
```

Hope this helps